# Importing Raster to PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster

I am new to PostGIS - on windows 10. I have managed to install it and have a database with vector data working in QGIS.

I am now trying load raster data.  I have edited the PATH to point to Postgres folder.

I can login to my database from a command window but when i type the raster2pgsql command at the hash prompt - nothing happens.

This is an example of the commands;

```
raster2pgsql -s 3035 g100_06.tif public.c-100 |psql -d CORINE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Edit your question and add the command you are trying with

Comment: What do you mean by the hash prompt? Are you logged into the database with psql? Raster2pgsql is a standalone executable and you must launch it directly from the command window.

Comment: To expand on what user30184 said, raster2pgsql is a normal command you run at a command prompt, which then pipes, the | sign, the output ( a bunch of insert statements) to the psql command to do the actual insert.

Comment: oops  - silly mistake - I know where to start now - thanks.